# egrep string case

Tags: regex, linux, shell

I have to grep from a file name temp which has something like this

```
Process             State  
BE_RP:1 [PL_2_3]    Running  
BE_RP:2 [PL_2_4]    Running  
BE_RP:3 [PL_2_5]    Running  
BE_RP:4 [PL_2_6]    Running  
FE_SCTP:0 [PL_2_3]  Running  
FE_SCTP:1 [PL_2_4]  Running  
BE_NMP:0            Not Running  
OAM:0               Running
```

I need to write a egrep statement which will return the number of process which are in running or not running state.

Comment: I posted with half info.. i want to ignore oam

Comment: This is a good use case for `awk`

Comment: In the future, notice that you are encouraged to edit your question if you want to clarify it. There is and "Edit" link just after the question.

Answer (score 2):

#### Running

```
$ grep -v 'OAM' input | grep -cP '(?<!Not) Running\s*$'
6
```

#### Not Running

```
$ grep -v 'OAM' input | grep -cP 'Not Running\s*$'
1
```

Comment: @user1081026. Add a `-E` option, try again.

Comment: Even with `-E` it might not recognize `\s` which is a Perlism. I would simply take out `\s*`, or trade `-E` for `-P` here as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/^OAM/ { next } /Not Running[ \t]*$/{s++} END {print s, NR-s-1}' foo.txt
```

Prints `<running>` `<not running>`

Comment: Edited to factor out `grep -v ^OAM`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '{
1 d
s/^[^:]*:[0-9]*[ ]*//
s/^[^]]*]//
s/^[ ]*//
}' input_file | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -P '^(?!OAM:0).*Running' temp | cut -f2 | wc -l
```